# Trying to say how long it takes to go somewhere and back again

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

How can I say this line in shorter and better English?

> It used to take 2.5 hours  to travel from my home to University and 2.5 hous to travel home. So, it used to take a total of about 5 hours a day.

How can I say it in a more concise way using standard English expressions?

Comment: At first, I thought you were asking us to proofread for you. (If we let ELL become a free proofreading service, then our site will be flooded with proofreading requests. We can't be given sentences out of a report, resume, or love letter that someone happens to be writing, and be asked to improve them.) However, as I looked more closely, I think I was able to figure out what you were getting at, so I've edited your question accordingly. I hope I'm on the right track. You might want to be more careful about titles and tags on future questions, to avoid the appearance of a proofreading request.

Comment: Thanks for the guideline, I'd be more specific about the title..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the expressions ***one-way*** and ***round trip***.

> It used to take 2.5 hours to travel from my home to University. So, I used to drive about 5 hours a day **round trip**.

Or:

> I would drive about 2.5 hours **one-way**, so it was a 5-hour **round trip** between home and school.

NOAD defines *round trip* as:

> **round trip**
>   (*noun*)
>   a journey to one or more places and back again.

These phrases can also be also be used as adjectives, and are sometimes hyphenated when used that way:

> *I would like to buy a one-way ticket to Baltimore, and a round-trip ticket to Paris*.

Comment: I would suggest that "one way" does not call for a hyphen when used as in your suggested wording. And that even though a hyphen might be only "sometimes used" when these terms are used as preposed adjective, it is always appropriate; some might say necessary. Otherwise it would be ambiguous, particularly as to whether the second ticket is "round".

Comment: @Brian - I mentioned the hyphen because [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/round-trip) adds a hyphen in the adjective form. However, when it comes to these hyphens, inconsistency abounds. One [travel blog](http://www.farecompare.com/travel-advice/one-way-tickets-vs-round-trip-tickets-which-are-cheaper/) even has this section header: _Comparing One-Way and Round Trip Ticket Prices_. As for the _round_ in _round trip_ being ambiguous, I think that's a bit of a stretch.